# QGIS 3.4.9 installer fails on qtquickcontrolsplugind.dll

Tags: installation

Running Windows Server 2016 standard. The installation will not continue.[image]

Comment: this is either a permissions issue or your disk is full

Comment: It is neither. The disk is gigantic and barely used and the installer is running as administrator to the default Program Files folder with no customizations made to its permissions.